# Get allocated memory size in iOS

Tags: ios

Is there a programatic way to get the size of allocated memory, either the total or just data, in iOS 5 and/or iOS 6?

I'm running into memory problems and I would like to understand the memory implications of some parallel image processing I'm doing as it is happening.

Comment: Can't you use instruments for this?

Comment: I want to find out in the middle of a particular bit of code how much memory I've allocated.  Instruments doesn't really target that sort of granularity.  Given that memory is a critical resource it seems that Apple ought to have provided an API to discover this information in your code.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [Instruments](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) for that purpose.

Instruments has a template called `Time Profile` which allows you to find which parts of your code are consuming the highest amount of time, you can track memory allocated in the go also.

Here [is a good start](http://www.raywenderlich.com/23037/how-to-use-instruments-in-xcode) if you are in the debut of your profiling experience.